# AJAX call reload only works once

Tags: javascript, ajax, reload

I am New to AJAX and have already asked a few question son this matter, but i have another, I use an AJAX call to auto save a value from a drop down list to database, this works great, however every time i change a value (Their are multiple drop downs with several values each can hold) I want the div to update to reflect the change in value. The AJAX I have is as follows:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function () {
          var statusVal = $(this).val();
          var job_id = $(this).prop('id');
          $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "saveStatus.php",
                   data: { statusType : statusVal, jobID: job_id },
            success: function(data) {   
                $('#div1').load('jobs.php #div1', function() {}); 

                   }
        })
    });
  });
</script>
```

So when I change a value in one drop down box (In div1) it refreshs the value, but if i was to change another value in the same or different drop down it no longer refreshs the div or saves the value to my DB, without the reload bit in my AJAX i can change the value in multple fields and it saves, but with the reload part it only happens once

**-----EDIT-----**

Ok further questioning, I have used

```
  $('#div1').on( 'change', 'select', function( ) {                                              
        var statusVal = $(this).val();
          var job_id = $(this).prop('id');
          $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "saveStatus.php",
                   data: { statusType : statusVal, jobID: job_id },

                   success: function(data) {   
                        $('#div1').load('jobs.php #div1', function() {});
                   }
        })
    });
  });
```

and that works great even for multiple select changes. However what if I have a few selects in a few divs, EG div1, div2 and div3. How can I adapt this code to be able to refresh all divs on a change in any of the divs, or is a case of just having the code 3 times adapted for each div.

**-----EDIT-----**
Thankyou all, I am able to do this with

```
$('#div1, #div2').on( 'change', 'select', function( ) { //stuff
```

Ian

Comment: What is the purpose of the `load` call inside the `success` handler?

Comment: On a tutorial I was following It had this line to refresh the div, I am super new to AJAX and don't really know what load does.

Comment: Well `load` is another AJAX call. So after your initial AJAX call you're making another one once that completes, back to `jobs.php`, is this right?

Comment: Jobs.php is the page with the div, all i want is for the values in drop downs to refresh with out the whole page refreshing.

Comment: Does `#div1` contain the `select` elements that should trigger this code? If you want to bind handlers to dynamically-added elements, you need to do delegation with `.on()`.

Comment: yes the select elements are inside div1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your listener is bound to the select element, which I'm betting is being blown away and relaced with the load(). Check out [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). jQuery makes it easy. Try binding the listener on '#div1'

```
$('#div1').on( 'change', 'select', function( e ) { //stuff
```

It should then apply to the refreshed content as well.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the above question to include some code that used the example you gave, But now I want to be able to refresh mutliple divs if a select in anyone of them changes, would i be able to do this or shall i just repeat the code for each

Comment: This code will listen for every select within #div1. You could attach the listener to the document or create a div that wraps all the other divs if you need to listen for them all. If you want to refresh _every_ div when _any_ select changes, just make your callback refresh them all. If the div you want to refresh is related to the select element that changes, you can access the triggering element within the callback (event.target) and determine the appropriate div. Also, as other commenters have mentioned, there is probably a better way to refresh than .load().